# Cross compiling snort using ptxdist results in INADDR_NONE configure error

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, autotools, configure, snort

I am very new to cross-compilation using ptxdist tool. I am using ptxdist version 2013.03.0 and trying to build snort 2.9.11.1 for arm cortex with linux kernel 4.9.47. However, when I run the `ptxdist prepare snort` command, it fails with the following error:

```
checking for strlcat... no
checking for strerror... yes
checking for vswprintf... yes
checking for wprintf... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking size of char... 1
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long int... 4
checking size of long long int... 8
checking size of unsigned int... 4
checking size of unsigned long int... 4
checking size of unsigned long long int... 8
checking for u_int8_t... yes
checking for u_int16_t... yes
checking for u_int32_t... yes
checking for u_int64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for boolean... no
checking for INADDR_NONE... configure: error: in `/home/user/snort-2.9.11.1':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I have checked the configure.in file. It tries to test the inet_addr() function with INADDR_NONE but fails. Following are the contents of snort's configure.in file:

```
# In case INADDR_NONE is not defined (like on Solaris)
have_inaddr_none="no"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for INADDR_NONE])
AC_RUN_IFELSE(
[AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
[[
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
]],
[[
    **if (inet_addr("10,5,2") == INADDR_NONE);**
    return 0;
]])],
[have_inaddr_none="yes"],
[have_inaddr_none="no"])
AC_MSG_RESULT($have_inaddr_none)
if test "x$have_inaddr_none" = "xno"; then
    AC_DEFINE([INADDR_NONE],[-1],[For INADDR_NONE definition])
fi
```

Is this the case of missing linux kernel headers in the cross-compilation toolkit or configure settings? I searched for the definition of INADDR_NONE in linux 4.9.47 source code and found it in

> ...linux.4.9.47/include/uapi/linux/in.h

Can anyone help me get around this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that `INADDR_NONE` is missing on the target (it likely is not), but that the configure test uses `AC_RUN_IFELSE`.  As its name says, and the error message indicates, `AC_RUN_IFELSE` tries to run code on the target, which does not work with cross-compiling.  This is a missing feature in the Snort build scripts: they are not ready for cross-building.

There are several ways to address this:

- **Fix Snort.**  The `AC_RUN_IFELSE` should likely be [`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Running-the-Compiler.html).  After all, if `INADDR_NONE` is not available, it should result in a compile-time failure, not an error at run time.  However, while this fix is trivial (don't forget to re-run `autoconf` after changing `configure.in`), there might be other problems because clearly, the software has not been cross-compiled in recent times.
- **Avoid cross-compiling.**  This does not mean that you should run the build on the actual target.  You could get a beefier system with an identical micro-architecture, or you could try [`qemu-user` emulation](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation).
- **Provide test results explicitly.**  You can override configure tests which use [`AC_CACHE_CHECK`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Caching-Results.html) and provide the results explicitly, when invoking `./configure`.  This does not appear to work for the broken test you encountered because it does not use `AC_CACHE_CHECK`, but it may help with something else.  The syntax for passing the pre-computed value is to set the variable in the *cache-id* argument of `AC_CACHE_CHECK` to the desired value when `./configure` is invoked, either in the argument or as an argument to the `./configure` script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Florian. The first method is not working. I will try the other ones.

Comment: I was able to cross-compile and run snort. Unfortunately, none of the above-mentioned options worked  for this particular problem but converting AC_RUN_IFELSE to AC_COMPILE_IFESLE worked to sort out daq features checking during the running of the configure script. For this particular INADDR_NONE problem, I had to patch the configure.in file that removed the checking of INADDR_NONE portion altogether.